# WebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync() method timesout each time for MNS access token

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, push-notification, windows-store-apps

I am trying to get the access token from MNS for Push notifications and the `WebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync()` method timesout each time. Any suggestions?

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx

Below is the code I use

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string postString = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com",
                              SID,
                              SECRET_KEY);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
        Stream newStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try rewriting it like this and see if it makes a difference. I've sometimes had problems with HttpWebRequest where WebRequest worked fine. Also make sure you close your streams.

```
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf");
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    string postString = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com",
                          SID,
                          SECRET_KEY);
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
    Stream newStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    newStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream() );
    string webResponse = requestReader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and it turned out to be a problem in different place than one would originally guess.

**You need to .Dispose()** or at least .Close() the **response** that you get from .GetResponseAsync, otherwise the next call to .GetRequestStreamAsync hangs.

It seems that the code behind this holds some limited (rather low) amount of sockets or locks, that disallow further requests to even begin until previous request has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Call `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on your Async method.

This [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) should explain the why and how.